# cannot find ActivityCreator.bat

Tags: android

I have recently started learning Android development. In the android-sdk/tools folder, there should be a command-line tool named ActivityCreator.bat, right? But I cant find it. Can anyone tell me why is it so? The version of android platform is 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new tool called "android" replaces the activitycreator script. Here is link for release notes from android 1.5. [Android 1.5 release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html)